# Add content to blade stack

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have a helper class to draw UI elements. Is it possible, in a method, to add content to a blade `@section` or `@stack`?

**EDIT:**

Here's an example that can clarify what i want to do: say i have some sidebar element that's being built using a `@stack('sidebar')`. I want to know if it is possible to add to this stack inside some helper class' method:

```
public function changeSidebar($content)
{
    $this->View->addToStack('sidebar', $content);
}
```

I'm assuming, of course, the existence of the `addToStack()` method in `View`.

Thanks in advance.